# Stack Exchangeのサイト一覧で、日本語SOの運営期間と訪問者数と分類が正しくない

Tags: バグ, 完了

URL: http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest

[image: all sites]

- 運営期間: 2013年11ヶ月より短いはず
- 訪問者数: 0 より多いはず
- 分類は ["Uncategorized"](http://stackexchange.com/sites#uncategorized-oldest) ではなく "Technology"?

HTML上の統計データのソース:

```
<input type="hidden" name="creation-date" value="-62135596800">
<input type="hidden" name="visits-per-day" value="0">
```

Comment: [メタSEで投稿済みです](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245386/whats-with-the-japanese-sos-stats/)